# Sending data from one tab to another tab in javafx 8 with eclipse and scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder, mediator

I created two Tabs with Scene Builder, one fxml-file for each tab. These two files are included in an main.fxml file. In Eclipse I have one controller for each fxml file (MainController, Tab1Controller, Tab2Controller). To shorten these explanation. I want to send or load Strings one tab to the other tab via MainController (Like the mediator pattern). But i get the following error code

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
```

/C:/Users/.../javafxmars/Test_TabController/bin/view/Main.fxml

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:14)
... 27 more
```

I searching for my mistake since a few days, but i cant find my anything. I looked for the ids a several times, but nothing. The FXML loader seems alright too.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

The MainController looks as followed:

```
public class MainController {

@FXML Tab1Controller tab1controller;
@FXML Tab2Controller tab2controller;

@FXML public void initialize(){
    System.out.println("Program initilized");
    tab1controller.init(this);
    tab2controller.init(this);
}

public String getTextloadedfromTab1() { 
    return tab1controller.label1.getText();
}

public void setTab2LabelText(String text) {
    tab2controller.label2.setText(text);
}
```

}

If i have to I post the code from the two tabs or the code for the fxml files. I will be glad, if someone could help me out.

**Here are the fxml documents**

[FXML Documents UPDATE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7iTnlcy161ZNkRMdFJrQXRfRVE)

These project is based on these tutorial https://github.com/goranvasic/JavaFxTutorials/tree/master/JavaFxCommunicationBetweenControllers

Comment: Could you also post your FXMl files? tab1controller or tab2controller (whatever is used in line MainController:14) is null.

Comment: thx for your comment. I added a link to the fxml documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main FXML you include the tabs like:

```
<fx:include fx:id="tab_Test1" source="tab/Tab_Test1.fxml" />
```

And then in your `MainController` you inject it like:

```
@FXML Tab1Controller tab1controller;
```

Which is not the correct way to do it. The valid name is **fx:idController** (fx id with a "Controller" suffix):

```
@FXML Tab1Controller tab_Test1Controller;
```

[Nested Controller naming.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)

Comment: I updated the files and renamed it as you recommended. So there will be no missunderstanding anymore. It helped little. I got a new error message. I will not post the whole code. /javafxmars/Test_TabController/bin/view/MainController.fxml:13  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set controller.tab.Tab1Controller field controller.MainController.tab1controller to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane

Comment: In your main FXML: <fx:include fx:id="tab1controller" source="tab/Tab1Controller.fxml" />  this is still wrong. Here the fx:id shall be "tab1"; and in you MainController it shall be injected as "@FXML Tab1Controller tab1Controller;".
What you do now, is to inject tab1controller, which is the id of the AnchorPane in your tab FXML (as it is the root of the FXML file) and that shall not be used as a Tab1Controller.

Comment: I have added you a link to how to name nested controllers in their FXML file and how to inject them into their parent Controller.

Comment: thank you very much, this was very helpful. I made it as you said. In MainController I renamed to this @ FXML Tab1Controller tab1Controller; @ FXML Tab2Controller tab2Controller; and in MainController.fxml in this <fx:include fx:id="tab1" source="tab/Tab1Controller.fxml" />